# Why not flag questions because they're homework?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, closing, homework

During last days a lot of people have sent so many questions that are like homework, for example:

- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021518/probability-question-help-please)
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021508/can-someone-please-help-me-prove-these-trig-identities)
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021698/lim-x-to0-fracxx-sin-x-frac6x2)
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021633/prove-that-by-proofs-types)
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021628/prove-that-f-is-discontinuous-on-mathbbr)
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021787/can-someone-please-help-me-prove-these-trig-identities-i-cant-figure-them-out)

and basically they don't make any effort to show what they have tried. It's possible to flag those questions because they're *do my homework* type?

Comment: This is what downvotes and close votes for. flag that need attention of moderators should be reserved for those that really need moderators involved.

Comment: While you don't have the close vote privilege (comes at 3k), you can flag for closure. Flag->Should be closed->Off topic->missing context. That sends the questions in the close vote review queue. The reviewers may or may not agree with your assessment. Close flags are handled by the community, not by moderators.

Comment: But "Off topic" would be if it doesn't have anything related to mathematics, don't?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Try on some question clicking doing what Daniel Fischer suggested. You will see that the whole close reason looks like this:  "This question is missing context or other details: Please [improve the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: Whether the phrase off-topic is really reasonable for this situation was discussed many times on meta. See for example [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19868/why-is-a-question-needing-more-details-called-off-topic) (and other questions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/19868)) or [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/add-an-explicit-needs-to-show-some-work-option-to-the-closing-form) (and other questions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16499))

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that your comment could be posted as an answer. (Perhaps with adding the full text of the close reason - since prvious comment by the OP suggests they might be a bit confused by the phrase "off topic".)